# Laravel5.8 Pusher not working. Cannot receive

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, pusher

I am creating realtime chat app.
I have set up pusher in my laravel and vue.js project.

But it doesn't work. Though I don't have any error in the console.
Also, I have no error in network tab.

I need to create messenger app, so I need a realtime chat function.
Now, I can push user's comment but in the other user's window, nothing shows up.

**But it does, once I refresh the page.** I think my pusher setting has something wrong, because in the pusher debug console, any session is not executed.

Here is my code.
.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

PUSHER_APP_ID=my id
PUSHER_APP_KEY=my app key
PUSHER_APP_SECRET= my secret key
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('my key'),
            'secret' => env('my secret key'),
            'app_id' => env('my id'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'ap3',
                'encrypted' => true,
            ],
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
```

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'my key',
    cluster: 'ap3',
    encrypted: true
});
```

NewMessage.php

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('messages.' . $this->message->to);
    }
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        $this->message->load('fromContact');
        return ["message" => $this->message];
    }
}
```

routes/channel.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
```

ContactsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Message;

class ContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function get() {
        $contacts = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->id())->get();//全部のcontactをjson経由でgetする

        return response()->json($contacts);    
    }

    public function getMessagesFor($id) {
        $messages = Message::where('from', $id)->orWhere('to', $id)->get();
        return response() -> json($messages);
    }

    public function send(Request $request) {
        $message = Message::create([
            'from' => auth()->id(),
            'to' => $request->contact_id,
            'text' => $request->text
        ]);



        return response()->json($message);
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried.

run all the command according to the laravel document.

**php artisan chache:clear**
and run the server again.

run **php artisan queue:work**
in command terminal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write

```
window.Echo.private('channelName').listen('EventName',function(e){
})
```

in your application to listen

Comment: Where is application file ?

Comment: In your component for example or in your app.js
You write the last code to handle the event fired in a channel your subscribed to it!

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it was the same. And I changed the pusher appname, then seems it worked in debug console. But still it doesn't work in my chat app. Please follow my answer. Hope you know some solutions regarding to this issue. Thank you so much !

Comment: @YoheiUmezu, try the above solution, but put the dot before EventName like ```listen('.EventName')```

Answer (score 0):

In your send() function you should write
`broadcast(new NewMessage($message));`
to broadcast the message.