# laravel broadcast disconnected on server

Tags: laravel, broadcast, pusher

I have used laravel broadcast on my website. It works fine in localhost but when I transferred my code on server , it does not work.

This is my chrome console:

```
Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
app.js?v=2530077509:39941 Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-us2.pusher.com:443/app/0fbe23f125be972b2221?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.2&flash=false"}]
app.js?v=2530077509:52795 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools
app.js?v=2530077509:52804 You are running Vue in development mode.
Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
app.js?v=2530077509:39941 Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> disconnected"]
```

Comment: does this help [Laravel5.8 Pusher not working. Cannot receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069389/laravel5-8-pusher-not-working-cannot-receive)

Comment: Do you receive any error messages? 
What differences are there between localhost and server hosting?